# String replace for Roman numerals

Tags: java, regex, roman-numerals, mvel

I am getting user Input like following.

"Both ix is viii are roman numeral.
mcmlxxxvii is wow year.
Year is mmxvi."

I have to search all roman numerals present in i/p and convert it to upper case. So i want to use string replace like below where xxx an be found roman numeric.

```
input.replaceAll("(?i)xxx","XXX");
```

Currently, i am able to check if input is having it or not.

```
System.out.println(input.matches("^.*M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}).*$"));
```

Help me in this.

Comment: Don't use anchors (`^` and `$`) if you want to match parts of a text

Comment: `replaceAll` won't help, search for `appendReplacement`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks but a proper regex is required for this.

Comment: It is impossible to do with 1 regex, you will need to use as many of them as there are possible values. It is not the way to proceed, so good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?!\bi+\b)\b[dcmlxvi]+\b|(\bi+\.)
```

and replace by this:

```
\U\1 will not work in java though,but the following code will
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/IZhwZa/9)

java code sample:

```
final String regex = "(?!\\bi+\\b)\\b[dcmlxvi]+\\b|(\\bi+\\.)";
String string = "i i Both ix is viii are roman numeral. mcmlxxxvii is wow year. Year is mmxvi. i i I i i i i am good";
String tmp;
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    tmp=matcher.group(0).toUpperCase();
    string=string.replace(matcher.group(0),tmp);
}

System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: This is failing if input starts with roman like "i. Both ix is viii are roman numeral. mcmlxxxvii is wow year. Year is mmxvi.". I am also getting same result with "\\b(M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))\\b".

Comment: so single 'i' individually is your problem right ? as it can be a Word and also can be a roman numeral... so you don't want to upper the single word i ?

Comment: watch my updated answer, which doesn't uppercase the word i

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working if it starts with "ii."

Comment: i am not actually clear, do you want to upper case ii to II or not ? if you dont want to upper case i or ii or iii or words formed with only i then i have updated my answer try now

Comment: Yes, In "i am sorry." i should not be capital. But in "i. sorry vii" or "ii. happy xii", we need to convert to uppercase.

Comment: @SatyabrataMahapatra I think your requirement is a bit strange but you can try now... your question should have been precised ... please look if now it solves your problem